# Could not connect: Access denied for user 'abc'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I am using `'mysql workbench'` and `'xampp'` server. I make the update to my database and try to view the results at 'localhost' and i get the error:

```
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'abc'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I remember that when i was working with mysql i did some changes and i dont know what exactly i did...I was just playing around with it. I googled to solve the error and did the following:

`mysql -u root -p hostname localhost`  -  I logged in as root

```
use mysql;

select * from user;
```

This gives  me four rows where i find the user `'abc'.`

I open my browser and try to view my webpage on `localhost` and `xampp` throws the above error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to connect with the user `abc` with the password. is it connecting or not by using the `mysql -u abc -p`

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ i just tried to login..I logged in successfuly..Better said there is no password for it!

Comment: @Sangamensh you need to give the password for that user.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ  I did give a password but still its the same..NOw i dont have any password for it and the host is "%"..So it has to connect to any host..BUt y is this error?? ..please help!!